# reactjs - export data to xlsx file using xlsx-style

Tags: reactjs, xlsx, js-xlsx

I am trying to export data to an excel file using xlsx-style, to add cells styling from the code.
I wrote the following code, and the file is downloaded fine but without the styles.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
    const addStyles = (workSheet) => {
        Object.entries(workSheet).filter(([k, v]) => k.charAt(0) === "A").forEach(([k, v]) => {
            v.s = {
                font: {
                    bold: true
                }
            }
        })
    }

    const saveFile = () => {
        const json = getJsonData();
        const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json, { skipHeader: true });
        addStyles(ws);
        const wb = { Sheets: { 'data': ws }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
        const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
        const fileData = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType });
        FileSaver.saveAs(fileData, fileName + fileExtension);
    }
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Naminee - I did not get along with this package but found something else very successful and easy to use. see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-export